# Change Color of Volume Columns (High/Low) in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I've got a simple chart showing candlesticks with volume columns underneath: http://jsfiddle.net/T83Xy/

Basically, I want to use black and red for the columns depending on whether it closes higher than the open or not.  I've seen some samples by pushing Y: data, color: '#000000' as the parameter.  The problem is I'm pushing a date and a volume number.  I attempted to push X: date, Y: data, color: '#000000' but it's throwing errors and not giving me the expected result.

Comment: use x: date (x should be lower case)

Comment: yes, sorry if i wasn't clear, i did try that.  I have to convert it to use braces {} to get the chart to even load, but it doesn't show any data: [http://jsfiddle.net/T83Xy/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/T83Xy/4/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first, you need to set [series.turboThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) to 0 if you have a big amount of points. This will disable the input data format check.

Then, to apply column colors depending on candles, I suggest you this piece of code:

```js
Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype.pointAttribs = (function(func) {
    return function(point, state) {
      var attribs = func.apply(this, arguments);
      
      var candleSeries = this.chart.series[0]; // Probably you'll need to change the index
      var candlePoint = candleSeries.points.filter(function(p) { return p.index == point.index; })[0];

      var color = (candlePoint.open < candlePoint.close) ? '#FF0000' : '#000000'; // Replace with your colors
      attribs.fill = state == 'hover' ? Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(0.3).get() : color;
      
      return attribs;
    };
}(Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype.pointAttribs));
```

Be careful as this code will affect ALL of your charts that currently on page. But you can easily add some conditions to run this only on specific chart. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lxc4h3f/) is a default Highstock demo with the code above.

Comment: You sir, are the man.  Question, and this may just be me misunderstanding how the function works, but I actually have 2 column series on my charts (one for volume, one for MACD with a Histogram).  This function is changing the colors on both, how can I modify it to focus only on series[1] - the volume series?

Comment: @Jake I slightly improved my fiddle - check it out. Now function will work only for first column serie. http://jsfiddle.net/T83Xy/10/

Comment: Seriously can't thank you enough, you made this easy to understand!!

Comment: @Igor Shastin It doesn't work either in jsfiddle or in my chart

Comment: @saitam Please check out this: https://jsfiddle.net/T83Xy/32/
I've changed it to meet updated charts

Comment: @IgorShastin: indeed, the /9 fiddle doesn't show colors, and the /32 one shows them, but overlapping the X axis labels. Also, could you please bring the code from JSFiddle into SO, now that it supports code snippets?

Comment: @DanDascalescu Updated my answer & dropped some code into it. Btw, original fiddle also have overlapping labels, so I think that's some chart model settings messed up. Anyway, I've added link to Highstock's demo with my code and it works like a charm. Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: In the meantime I've posted what I think is the [current best practice for volume bar colorization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779026/1269037), without overriding methods.

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me:

```js
$(function () {
jQuery.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data) {

    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    var volumeColor = '';
    var ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        dataLength = data.length,
        // set the allowed units for data grouping
        groupingUnits = [[
            'week',                         // unit name
            [1]                             // allowed multiples
        ], [
            'month',
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ]],

        i = 0;

    for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
        ]);
         if (i==0) {
        volumeColor = '#CCCCCC';
         } else {         
            if (data[i][1] >= data[i-1][1]) {
               volumeColor = '#006633';
            } else {
               volumeColor = '#CC0033';
            }
         }

        volume.push({
            x: data[i][0], // the date
            y: data[i][5],
            color: volumeColor
        });
    }


    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Historical'
        },

        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: '60%',
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: '65%',
            height: '35%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: ohlc,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1,
            turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE,
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false,
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }]
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height:400px;min-width:310px"></div>
```

Comment: To colorize candles, the code should [compare the open with the close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779026/1269037); not with the previous candle.

Answer (score 1):

The current (HighCharts 7+) solution for this, which doesn't require overriding any methods, is to simply set the `color` attribute for the volume point according to the comparison between the current candlestick point's open and its close: green if `<`, red if `>`, and yellow if equal.

Here is a minimal example.

```js
// Return a color matching the candle by comparing the open (1) and close (4)
function volumeBarColor(point) {
  if (point[1] < point[4])
    return 'green';
  if (point[1] > point[4])
    return 'red';
  return 'yellow';
}

Highcharts.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-ohlcv.json', data => {

  // Split the data set into ohlc and volume
  const ohlc = [],
      volume = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    ohlc.push([
      data[i][0], // the date
      data[i][1], // open
      data[i][2], // high
      data[i][3], // low
      data[i][4], // close
    ]);

    volume.push({
      x: data[i][0], // the date
      y: data[i][5], // the volume
      color: volumeBarColor(data[i]),
    });
  }


  // Create the chart
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    title: {
      text: 'AAPL Historical'
    },

    yAxis: [{
      labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3
      },
      height: '60%',
    }, {
      labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3
      },
      top: '65%',
      height: '35%',
      offset: 0,
    }],

    series: [{
      type: 'candlestick',
      name: 'AAPL',
      data: ohlc,
    }, {
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Volume',
      data: volume,
      yAxis: 1,
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```