# Highcharts update grouped data point color

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to update the color of a single point in a grouped data set?  I can't seem to find a way to reliably set the colors.

A fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x4gy675f/) demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points are grouped during the rendering process of the chart so they cannot be specifically targeted via constructor options (because we don't know which points will be generated by Highcharts algorithms).

What is more, Higcharts doesn't allow performing `update` function on the grouped point.

As a **workaround** your can change the CSS of point's SVG element:

```
chart.series[0].groupedData[0].graphic.css({
    color: 'red'
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9ey2yq3u/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#css

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I am using a candlestick chart.  That solution works for the fill colors, but does not change the color of the line unfortunately.

Comment: You can change the `stroke` property too: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w1wg486z/