# Highchart change column color by value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to Highchart but going to create candlestick chart and column chart.

I created it thanks to samples, but I can't customize its color.

Candlestick highstock chart has *upcolor* and *color* attribute to change color but column chart hasn't.

I tried to use *zone* or *colorseries* but we need to compare data to set color of column, so need to create func.

i.e data has 2 values *open*, *close*, *qty*.
Column height is set by *qty*, but its color needs to be set if open is bigger than close red, if not blue.

How can I do this?

```
var chart1 = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    margin: [10, 80,10, 10],
    resetZoomButton: {
        position: {
            x: 0,
            y: -100
        }
    }
},

plotOptions:{
    column:{
         color:green /* Here I want to set func to change color of column*/
    }
}
    yAxis:[{
        labels: {
            enabled:false,
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        top: '80%',
        height: '20%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0
    }],
    tooltip: {
        split: true
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Quantity',
        data: Quantity,
        yAxis: 1,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: groupingUnits
        }
    }]
});
```

When you try to remove series and add the same series, it is not working.

Please have a look at this [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xxfo5s3x/4).

It works at the first time but if you change series using dropdown (series[0].remove and addSeries() is used) error is showing on console.

That error is in load event.
I think that func is triggered when you delete the series data.

Comment: can you add a [mcve] of what you have tried and what it is not working?

Comment: I added code but plotoption has no func to set color.

Comment: can you explain with real example https://jsfiddle.net/y8xokfjr/ what you want and what do you mean by _data has 2 values open, close, qty. Column height is set by qty, but its color needs to be set if open is bigger than close red, if not blue._

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As you know that column chart is showing volume from data. But I want to change the color of column according to open and close. So If open from candlestick is bigger than close from candle stick, then show green bar, if not show red bar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts Update Grouped Series Data Point Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724042/highcharts-update-grouped-series-data-point-colors)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to work when you exec addSeries() func. but it shows error now.

Comment: This minimal demo may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w1wg486z/  `colorSeries` function can be called anytime to color a series passed as an argument. It finds the corresponding points in baseline series (candlestick) and uses it to determine colors for another series (column). It works both for grouped and non-grouped points. It also utilizes `addSeries` and it doesn't produce an error.